# Connecting to a Oracle SQL DB in PS

Tags: powershell, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to log into a Oracle DB run a query in it then output the results in a file csv or txt doesn't really matter and then send an email depending of the results.
Can't use the automated mail sending included in the Ora DB because of user privilege not high enough

I tried to use the add-type with the path of the Oracle.ManagedData

`Add-Type -Path "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\Desktop\ora\lib\net462\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"`

but i'm getting way too much errors mostly keywords not supported in the current language version

How can i connect to an oracle SQL instance with powershell with the minimum stuff to download (none if possible) and then query a select in it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the _first_ error you get?

Comment: It depends on the driver you use.  See https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/. With oracle I usually recommend using ODBC.  Once you download the driver and setup the ODBC connection then you can use followiong : https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/oracledb-odbc-powershell.rst?force_isolation=true

Comment: here are the results of :
 `try
{
  // Add-Type -Path "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\ora\lib\net462\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  if (ex is System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException)
  {
    var typeLoadException = ex as ReflectionTypeLoadException;
    var loaderExceptions  = typeLoadException.LoaderExceptions;
  }
}`
The 'var' keyword is not supported in this version of the language

Also i can barely download anything or install drivers on the company's laptop

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.